# Set theory models logic

Tags: logic

I have the statement:
$\mathfrak{M}\models\forall x\forall y (R(x,y)\to R(y,x))[h]$

I must write equivalent statements to this

So I said:

For all,$d\in\mathfrak{M}(\forall)$, $\mathfrak{M}\models\forall y(R(x,y)\to R(y,x))[h[x/d]]$

Then I said:

For all,$c,d\in\mathfrak{M}(\forall)$, $\mathfrak{M}\models(R(x,y)\to R(y,x))[h[x/d][y/c]]$

So:

For all,$c,d\in\mathfrak{M}(\forall)$,$\mathfrak{M}\not\models R(x,y)[h[x/d][y/c]]$,or,$\mathfrak{M}\models R(y,x)[h[x/d][y/c]]$

So:
$\langle[[x]]_{h[x/d][y/c]}^{\mathfrak{M}},[[y]]_{h[x/d][y/c]}^{\mathfrak{M}}\rangle\not\in\mathfrak{M}(R)$ or,$\langle[[y]]_{h[x/d][y/c]}^{\mathfrak{M}},[[x]]_{h[x/d][y/c]}^{\mathfrak{M}}\rangle\in\mathfrak{M}(R)$

Is this correct? And how must I go further?

Comment: to go further to achieve what?

Comment: how can I write $[[x]]_{h[x/d][y/z]}^{\mathfrak{M}}$\, easier for example?

Comment: $R(x,y)[x/d,y/c]$

Comment: The more cumbersome notation $\varphi(x)h[x/d]$ is needed in order to avoid confusing the *assignment* of an object of the domain as reference for a variable ($h[x/d]$ is $h(x)=d$) from the substitution of a *constant* (a term of the language) in place of a variable into a formula $\varphi[x/c]$